# Unsupported configuration: Initial position of this window is outside of this machine's screen

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am developing a Mac app based on NSDocument using Swift. After working for many cycles it suddenly stopped showing its initial (and the only) window. Its showing a warning message(text in the title). Even switching to the earlier working version didn't help.
The app window doesn't show up in the expose or mission control. In fact the program doesn't even hit the windowControllerDidLoadNib function. The code is AppDelegate is being executed though.

I am running Xcode 6.4 on Yosemite.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Ok, the window shows up when I click the Dock icon. But won't show up when launched.

Comment: BTW there is one window per document -> are you developing single window app or document based app? How can you see text in the title if there is no window. Sample project or better description with pictures ...

Comment: Is the position of the window (auto)saved? Is the initial position of the window in the xib (size inspector in Xcode) ok?

Comment: @xhurso00 I am new to Xcode. The app is really a database-based app with one window (a data entry form) to begin with.

Comment: @Willeke I tried both checking and unchecking Restorable checkbox in IB, if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: I mean 'Autosave' in the Attributes inspector of Xcode, or the windowFrameAutosaveName property of NSWindowController.

Comment: Where and when do you get the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps although it is late.

1. set the screen display resolution of your Mac to the highest
2. make your window center and auto size in IB
3. build and save your project
4. change your Mac's resolution to you prefer
5. re-open your project

Comment: Jiulong, I am not sure what was wrong but it somehow got sorted out. The app window shows itself and I don't get the warning any more. I moved to a new machine which might be the reason. Thanks for your help though.